# Display Folder Contents of Specific Filetype in C# Listview

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm using Visual C# 2010 Express. What I'm trying to do is list all files within a, predefined, directory of a specific filetype. With each listing having a check box beside it. So that the same command can be, individually,  run on all marked files.

I've used a cmd.exe batch script to do something similar in the past. But I don't know how to translate it into C#. For use with System.Windows.Forms.ListView. At least I think I want to use ListView. Nor am I aware as to how I would append a check box to the beginning of each filename listing.

Batch example:

```
@echo off
REM Path variable set for sake of example.
set "path=c:\temp" 

:fList REM File List Loop
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
For /F "delims=" %%A In ( ' DIR /B /O:N /A:-D "%path%\*.ext" ' ) Do (
echo %%A
)
goto :EOF
```

Thanks in advance for any help or suggested reading material.

Comment: So you're starting from scratch, with no knowledge of C# or Windows Forms programming?  If so, then I would start with Google to find some tutorials.  If not, then show us the C# code that you have so far.

Comment: I have a basic working knowledge of c# in terms of console applications. I'm more or less just getting started on Windows Forms however. Just wanted to throw a GUI over something I'd been working on. However I don't have any preexisting code pertaining to this particular dilemma. This is something of a new addition.

Comment: You can get files in a directory using `Directory.GetFiles("%path%", "*.ext")`, add them to a `CheckedListBox`, then iterate over the `CheckedListBox.CheckedItems` property to perform the commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the files, you can use `Directory.GetFiles(path, extension)` if you have a single extension. In my example, I made a method to work with multiple extensions.

Instead of the ListView, you can also use a CheckedListBox, which already have the checkboxes you need.
You can get the files (with desired extensions) and fill the checkedListBox like this :

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        const string path = @"c:/yourpath";
        List<string> extensions = new List<string> { "EXE", "PNG" };

        string[] files = GetFilesWithExtensions(path, extensions);
        checkedListBox1.Items.AddRange(files);
    }

    private string[] GetFilesWithExtensions(string path, List<string> extensions)
    {
        string[] allFilesInFolder = Directory.GetFiles(path);
        return allFilesInFolder.Where(f => extensions.Contains(f.ToUpper().Split('.').Last())).ToArray();
    }
```

Of course, if you only need .ext as an extension, it would look like this instead :

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        const string path = @"c:/yourpath";
        const string extension = "*.ext";

        checkedListBox1.Items.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(path, extension));
    }
```

Once the user checks the files he needs and, for example clicks a button, you can get the selected elements like this :

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckedListBox.CheckedItemCollection selectedFiles = checkedListBox1.CheckedItems;
        //Do stuff with files
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That did the trick quite nicely. Explanation & examples are clear & concise.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the folder in a directory you want to do something like this:

```
string myDir = @"c:\";
string wildcard = "*.ext";
var files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(myDir,wildcard);
```

In order add these files to a list view this is a decent starting point link:

- [MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.forms.listview.items%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

this is a code snippet from the above link:

```
   void CreateMyListView()
        {

                          // Create a new ListView  control.
                ListView listView1 = new ListView();
                listView1.Bounds = new Rectangle(new Point(10,10), new Size(300,200));

                          // Set the view to show details.
                listView1.View = View.Details;
                // Allow the user to edit item text.
                listView1.LabelEdit = true;
                // Allow the user to rearrange columns.
                listView1.AllowColumnReorder = true;
                // Display check boxes.
                listView1.CheckBoxes = true;
                // Select the item and subitems when selection is made.
                listView1.FullRowSelect = true;
                // Display grid lines.
                listView1.GridLines = true;
                // Sort the items in the list in ascending order.
                listView1.Sorting = SortOrder.Ascending;

                // Create three items and three sets of subitems for each item.
                ListViewItem item1 = new ListViewItem("item1",0);
                // Place a check mark next to the item.
                item1.Checked = true;
                item1.SubItems.Add("1");
                item1.SubItems.Add("2");
                item1.SubItems.Add("3");
                ListViewItem item2 = new ListViewItem("item2",1);
                item2.SubItems.Add("4");
                item2.SubItems.Add("5");
                item2.SubItems.Add("6");
                ListViewItem item3 = new ListViewItem("item3",0);
                // Place a check mark next to the item.
                item3.Checked = true;
                item3.SubItems.Add("7");
                item3.SubItems.Add("8");
                item3.SubItems.Add("9");

                // Create columns for the items and subitems.
                listView1.Columns.Add("Item Column", -2, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
                listView1.Columns.Add("Column 2", -2, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
                listView1.Columns.Add("Column 3", -2, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
                listView1.Columns.Add("Column 4", -2, HorizontalAlignment.Center);

                //Add the items to the ListView.
                        listView1.Items.AddRange(new ListViewItem[]{item1,item2,item3});

                // Create two ImageList objects.
                ImageList imageListSmall = new ImageList();
                ImageList imageListLarge = new ImageList();

                // Initialize the ImageList objects with bitmaps.
                imageListSmall.Images.Add(Bitmap.FromFile("C:\\MySmallImage1.bmp"));
                imageListSmall.Images.Add(Bitmap.FromFile("C:\\MySmallImage2.bmp"));
                imageListLarge.Images.Add(Bitmap.FromFile("C:\\MyLargeImage1.bmp"));
                imageListLarge.Images.Add(Bitmap.FromFile("C:\\MyLargeImage2.bmp"));

                //Assign the ImageList objects to the ListView.
                listView1.LargeImageList = imageListLarge;
                listView1.SmallImageList = imageListSmall;

                // Add the ListView to the control collection. 
                this.Controls.Add(listView1);
            }
```